# CSS Height % Not working in Android App Screen

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

I have an app that delivers screen content in an html format, pulled from a database. I need to work in percentages for width & height of elements that make up the display, to accommodate various devices. I can't get the height % to work in any components, no matter what I try. I've reduced the layout to the simplest format for troubleshooting and am including it here. I've assigned background colors to elements so as to see the effects of code modifications.

In the screenshot I've attached, the yellow background is part of the background art. The yellow HTML color attribute is hidden behind the red Body color, but should be showing at 100% height if working properly. This is my display code, simplified:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<style> 
*{ margin:0;   padding:0;}       
html { width:100%;  min-height:100%;  background:yellow;}          
body { width:100%;  min-height:100%;  background:red;} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="height: 100%; background:white;">
<tr >
<td width="275" height="200" bgcolor="blue"></td>
<td width="275" height="200" bgcolor="brown"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" width="450" height="300" bgcolor="green"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" width="450" height="300" bgcolor="black"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the screen shot of the app in a Nexus 7:
[image: Screen Shot of Code Render]

Thanks for any help getting me through this.

Cayce

The Android Project Manifest.XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paulistpress.ordo"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="OrdoAppActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



>>>>>>>>>>> Two places of WebView codes, as per my notes >>>>>>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/view_about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="88" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/view_symbols"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="88" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not likely to be with the HTML, but rather with the WebView/Layout you haven't posted. Add the Layout.

It's likely that you have some padding or margins on the Views or that you have a webview not set to match_parent height

Comment: Can't believe I missed your reply. I really need to get this worked out.

Comment: If you add your layout XML we can see what the issue is

Comment: I've added the Manifest.xml code, thinking this is where the WebView code should be. If I sound new to this environment, I am. My developers are out for the weekend and I'm trying to get a resolution sooner. As a web developer for twenty years, I'm comfortable editing in the ADT, if I can just be pointed in the right direction. Learning my way around.

Thanks again.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but in my res/layout folder, there are two dedicated files for two specific html-driven pages in the app. These are the About page, and one called Symbols. These are static, while the other s a database receiver. These are the webview codes in each of those xml files:

Comment: oops... I'll add that up top.

Comment: You need to start by opening the activity you are using. Look for the line that says setContentView(...), The value will be R.layout.<Something>, you need to find the layout called <Something>.xml in res/layout and the contents of that file are what you need to post